# IVH TreeView Twistie's are not triggering the functions binded with it

Tags: javascript, angular, treeview

I have the IVH treeview implemented and runs fine.

But at runtime, I need to get 'children' data for my JSON,
So Tried to bind my API call to Collapsed Twistie of IVH TreeView as shown below, but it does not trigger the function `getChildrenNodes(node.Code)`. can someone help me with this, please?

```
    app.config(['ivhTreeviewOptionsProvider',
    function (ivhTreeviewOptionsProvider) {
        ivhTreeviewOptionsProvider.set({
            idAttribute: 'Code',
            labelAttribute: 'Name',
            childrenAttribute: 'children',
            selectedAttribute: 'selected',
            useCheckboxes: true,
            expandToDepth: 0,
            defaultSelectedState: true,
            validate: true,
            twistieExpandedTpl: '<span class="show-hide"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>',
            twistieCollapsedTpl: '<span ng-show="node.HasChildren" ng-click="getChildrenNodes(node.Code)" class="show-hide"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>',
            twistieLeafTpl: '',
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example using the template in the project README showing it now working? Here was an example showing how to do what you're after by making a fancy directive for your leaf nodes: http://jsbin.com/yowave/7/edit?js,output (note that the API that was used for this example doesn't seem to be working any longer).

Comment: http://jsbin.com/secitun/edit?html,js,output If you have a look at my JSON, I have a field "HasChild", if that is true, Twistie plus should be visible, and on click I will get my children from the API call(I have not added that in jsbin for now). But as per the IVH plugin, the "plus" twistie doesnt show up if there is no children.

Comment: after adding the ASCII checbox, I am not able to click on it but on label :( Twisties are not showing as well

Comment: You want the *leaf* template to be dynamic. The leaf template can show a clickable "plus" (same as expand template) if `HasChild` is `true`.

Comment: @jtrussell why I am I have to use `"$scope.$parent.trvw.root()"` to access root of the tree. `trvw` is returning undefined. hence checkbox selection is not happening :(

Comment: You should use `ivhTreevewMgr` to make selections outside of node templates. Otherwise you need to require ivhTreeview as a parent and grab a reference to its controller: https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/0531a2ee97fa64a48ee57d94b6d928de9e834226/src/scripts/directives/ivh-treeview-twistie.js#L17.

Comment: I have this line in my code :( `require: '^ivhTreeview',`

Comment: Any you get `trvw` as the 4th parameter to your directive's link function? https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/0531a2ee97fa64a48ee57d94b6d928de9e834226/src/scripts/directives/ivh-treeview-twistie.js#L31

Comment: it returns`undefined` for me, Russel, believe me :(

Comment: I believe you - it's tough to say what's going on without a full demo though. See this example - I updated it so that the leaf directive gets a reference to `trvw` and you can see it is defined (it logs out the value of `trvw` when you click a leaf twistie) http://jsbin.com/yuledelovo/edit?js,console,output.